# Make coloring of rects dependent on data value of those rects using d3.js, and regraphing

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, colors, updates

Currently I am graphing a treeMap in d3 and I have a colorList of two colors. I would like to make so that the colors of the rects are dependent on the size of the rects, so the maximum size is  one color, and the minimum size is another color. I would also like to linearly make the colors less opaque depending on their size, and then I would like to regraph these when the data changes.

So I am curious, how do you make this type of color setting function in d3.js? And for some reason my graph is not updating when I call   redrawGraphFromJson(data). Thanks for your help.

This is my current code.

```
var colorList=['#F80000','#4682B4'];

function drawTreeMap(array1,array2){
        console.log("got to drawing");
        nestedJson=createObj(array1, array2);
            w = 1880 - 80,
            h = 900 - 180,
            x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
            y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
            color = d3.scale.ordinal().range([colorList[0]]),   //d3.scale.category10(),
            root,
            node;


            treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
                .round(false)
                .size([w, h])
                .sticky(true)
                .padding([10, 0, 0, 0])
                .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

            svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
                .attr("class", "chart")
                .style("width", w + "px")
                .style("height", h + "px")
              .append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h)
              .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");


              node = root = nestedJson;

              var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
                  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

              var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
                  .data(nodes)
                  .enter().append("svg:g")
                  .attr("class", "cell")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
                  .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

              cell.append("svg:rect")
                  .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
                  .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy ; })
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });

              cell.append("svg:text")
                  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
                  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .text(function(d) { return (d.name+",--  "+d.size); })
                  .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });




              d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

              d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
                treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
                zoom(node);
              });

    }
    function redrawGraphFromJson(data) {
      treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
        .round(false)
        .size([w,h])
        .value(function(d) { return d.number; })
        .sticky(true);

      // Draw the graph
      node = root = data;
      var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
                  .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

      var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
        .data(nodes);

  }
```

Comment: You could use a scale for the colours.

Comment: could you reference me to an example.

Comment: See for example http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2011/08/11/d3-scales-and-color/

Comment: thanks, for the help, the scale coloring works. Any thoughts on the updating, I looked at some older posts and tried setting the treemap to .sticky(false), but that didn't work.

Comment: Well, how is it not working? What's happening and what would you like to happen instead?